# Codeigniter how to return multiple rows from same column in model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to get all the rows which are filters by the query. But only the first row is returned from the model to the controller.

Given below is my model function. How to get all the data needed?

```
public function getOfferTags($param) {

    $this->db->select('tags.*');
    $this->db->from('tags');
    $this->db->join('offer_tag', 'offer_tag.tag_id = tags.id');
    $this->db->join('offers', 'offers.id = offer_tag.offer_id');
    $this->db->where('offers.id', $param);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();    

}
```

Comment: Could you return the query rather than a single row, then loop over it, or `return $query->result_array()`

Comment: Sorry I am new to CI. When I check the returned values on the controller only the first row is returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply not return row and on that place fetch as an array form like

```
return $query->result_array();
```

After that checks in controller and get the result in array.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add, because you are new to CI, that you should always check if their are rows before using the array to prevent notices or issues. with mehta's method you would do `if(count($rows) > 0) { //rows exist } else { // no rows, display error .etc. }` or you can do:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result_array(); // or result() for obj
}
return false;
```

Usage:

```
if ($this->somemodel->getOfferTags($stmt)) {
    // has data
} else {
    // no data
}
```

It is important to start with good practices and this will help ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely follow the above practise